# ios - sqlite bad access, fails only in iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using a procedure that involves consultation with a local database if there is any record saved, and operates in a iphone 4, 5 and 5s, but not in a iphone 6, all with ios 8.1, I hope your help.

[image: example of error in iphone 6]

Edited: 
i omitted all code

```
-(int)getCountRowsLogin{
NSString *ubicacionDB = [self obtenerBD];

if(!(sqlite3_open([ubicacionDB UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK))
{
    NSLog(@"No se puede conectar con la BD");
}
int numero = 0;
NSString *query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registro";
sqlite3_stmt *sentencia;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &sentencia, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(sentencia) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        int cuenta = sqlite3_column_int(sentencia, 0);
        numero = cuenta;
        sqlite3_finalize(sentencia);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
return numero;
```

}

Comment: Post code not the image. Thank you.

Comment: thanks, some idea to solve this?

Comment: So many mistakes. You close but don't open the database. You only finalize the prepared statement if you read any records.

Comment: thanks @rmaddy i edited the question please watch it. the strange thing is that the iphone 4s and 5 it works

Comment: I found the problem, change $(ARCHS_STANDARD) to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT), that is why it does not work in 64bit.
i don't know if I can upload it to the AppStore whit this architecture?

Comment: Your updated code is almost worse. You open the database but you only close it if you can prepare the statement. You should close the database no matter what if you open it. You finalize the statement inside the while loop. That's bad. Put the call to finalize where the call to close is at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Use fileSystemRepresentation instead of UTF8String to convert an NSString into a const char * for use in a "C" API (such as SQLite3).

Comment: i tried but no resolves my problem, thanks. the problem is sqlite3_finalize(sentencia) because it's inside of while, now run

Comment: also, I see that you test for sqlite3_open to fail, but it doesn't do an early return.  There is nothing to prevent the code from continuing on to try and use the (not opened) database.  I'd add a return statement after NSLog(@"No se puede conectar con la BD");